# Make Discord Request With NodeJS (Change Vanity Discord)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a bot that can change url code with a request, but i've tried something, and it's only returning the current invite code

My code:

```js
fetch('https://www.discord.com/api/v6/guilds/762359120031907871/vanity-url', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bot ' + client.token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                payload: JSON.stringify({
                        "code":"test458"
                      })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => { console.log(json)})
```

And it's returning

```js
{ code: 'cherrys', uses: 0 }
```

I just want to change the code, but idk how i can do that, and when i try with a user token it say

```
401: Unauthorized
```

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix `Bot` on the Autorization header is only for Bots, if you want to use a user token, you need to use `Bearer` prefix instead of the bot ones.

```js
fetch('https://www.discord.com/api/v6/guilds/762359120031907871/vanity-url', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${client.token}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                payload: JSON.stringify({
                        "code":"test458"
                      })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => { console.log(json)});
```